# PHP Ajax not creating post variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

A while ago i made a search function with ajax and php. You could fill in a textbox with text and it would try to find a match among all countries stored in the database.
Now i am refining the code and making it PDO, but i broke something and i cant find out what.

this is my plain HTML

```
<head>
    <title>Ajax</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
            <h1 class="title">Enter your country please</h1>

        <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off" onchange="">
            <h4 id="results-text">Showing results for: <b id="search-string">Array</b></h4>

        <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

here is my Jquery and javascript. note i have not changed anything to the HTML nor javascript so it can not by a type error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert('asdf');

function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#search').val();
    $('b#search-string').html(query_value);

    if(query_value !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#results").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}

$("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    if (search_string == '') {
        $("ul#results").fadeOut();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
    }

    else {
        $("ul#results").fadeIn();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });
});
```

And here is my Search.PHP

```
<?php
class SearchEngine{

    private $html;

    public function __construct($conn){

        $this->html = '<li class="result">
                            <h3>NameReplace</h3>
                            <a target="_blank" href="ULRReplace"></a>
                        </li>';

        if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
            $search_string = $_POST['query'];
        }

        else{
            $search_string = '';
            echo('Something went wrong, post query not set');
        }


        //$search_string = mysql_real_escape_string($search_string);

        if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM country WHERE name LIKE "%' . $search_string . '%"';
            $result = $conn->prepare($query);
            $result->execute();
            $result_array = $result->fetchAll();

                foreach ($result_array as $result) {
                    $display_name = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['name']);
                    $display_url = 'sadf';

                    $output = str_replace('NameReplace', $display_name, $this->html);
                    $output = str_replace('ULRReplace', $display_url, $output);
                    echo($output);
                }
        }
    }

}
```

?>

The problem:

the Post query is never created, for this i made a isset so for now when there is no Post Query created. It will create a Post Query with value "B".

Any help will be much appreciated. Please be gentle i am new to Ajax and i rather want to understand than have the solution. Thank you

Comment: if the POST is never created, that is most certainly a Javascript problem. Looking through to see if I can see anything. Very specifically it sounds like the .live is not being invoked on keyup

Comment: Have you instantiated your SearchEngine class?

Comment: @DJDarkViper Thank you, that's what i thought to but i just can't find it. I bet in the end its the most obvious human error.

Comment: @JonathanSimas what do you mean insatatiated searchEngine class?

Comment: side note: [As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @Sean that was exactly what my next train of thought was. I cannot remember the last time I used Live. I always used `$.keyup` for this kind of behaviour

Comment: @Sean Sigh all these problems exists thanks to PHP moving towards PDO and now even Jquery is deprecating functions. Thanks for the heads up though! so i can fix that when i fix the current problem!

Comment: Instantiation is to create a new instance of a class, something like: $seach = new SearchEngine(); ....

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with JQuery, two entirely separate worlds by organization's who dont talk nor take inspiration from eachother lol

Comment: Why are you using a `mysql_` function -> `$search_string = mysql_real_escape_string($search_string);`. Since you are using PDO and do not have a `mysql_connect` this will not work.

Comment: I didnt say they were the same or anything in that direction. sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Well, in that case the POST would return a 500, which is out of scope for this particular problem

Comment: Oh, god! You cannot use a class without instantiate it, your code is never readed...

Comment: @Sean i commented that part out of the code but i didnt update the question here. i only kept it in to remember myself to created a code/function that filters some characters. but that particular code is commented to not work

Comment: @JonathanSimas i have no idea what you actually mean? what does instantiate mean? what is wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You have just a Class in your Search.PHP file. It will not do anything with your requests if you don't have a code like  $seach = new SearchEngine(); in your page. Your _construct function will never run...

Comment: @JonathanSimas I called the class inside my index.php '$SearchEngine = new SearchEngine($conn);'

Comment: But your ajax url is search.php... I'm getting confused. Are you sure your PHP is executing? please execute this in the first line of the _construct function: var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @JonathanSimas What do you mean ajax url? Note i am a noob in PHP and Ajax. So my code could be the biggest mess you have ever seen but for me this is the best i could make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not point the right URL! Look:

You have pointed your ajax request to search.php :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search.php",
```

But you have just a class in search.php. A class don't do anything by itself. You have to Instantiate and call its methods/functions. Please compare these 2 pieces of code:

```
<?php
//server.php
//Doing nothing
class SearchEngine{

    private $html;

    public function __construct($conn){
     echo "I'm executing";
    }
}
?>
```

let's say you have this in server.php

```
<?php
//server.php
//It will print "I'm executing" in the screen
class SearchEngine{

    private $html;

    public function __construct($conn){
     echo "I'm executing";
    }
}

$search = new SearchEngine($conn);

?>
```

To solve your original problem You have to to point your ajax to the page having the INSTANTIATION code, not the class, like this:

```
//index.php
//Let's suppose you have this code in your index.php
$SearchEngine = new SearchEngine($conn);
```

So your JQuery ajax code should looks like that:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
```

Comment: Oh wow, i never thought of that and it instantly makes sense!. Thanks a lot for your help. not only did you solve my problem but you also helped me learn!

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned by Sean, in the comments, the $.live jquery method is deprecated in your version of jQuery.

Try utilizing $.keyup instead

```
$("input#search").keyup(function() {
   // stuff
});
```

Comment: Yes i just read it. Is there any difference in the new functions or can i just replace it without problems?

Comment: Just replace the the line involing your $.live declaration, no other changes needed

Comment: I replaced it without doing anything else and it worked instantly!